# Cannot save object to localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, javascript-objects

I am building a bookcase to store information about books that someone is reading. I want to be able to store whatever information has been entered so that it doesn't disappear after page refresh. I am trying to use localstorage but so far I cannot get it to print the information after page load.

I really have tried many options already and this is what I am working with now.

Please note, the code has been minimalised to make it easier to deal with.

I appreciate the help.

EDIT:If I try console.log or alert I get a null message.

```js
let retrieveBookShelf = localStorage.getItem("storedbookShelf");

let bookShelf = JSON.parse(retrieveBookShelf);


const
  shelf = document.getElementById('shelf')
, addBookBtn = document.getElementById('add-book')
, myForm = document.getElementById('form')
, formDiv = document.getElementById('formcontainer')
, submitFormBtn = document.getElementById('submitform')
, booksElms = [];


class BookDetails {
    constructor(title){
        this.title = title
    }
}

addBookBtn.addEventListener('click', () => 
  {
 
  let book = document.createElement('div');
  book.classList.add('book');
  shelf.appendChild(book);
  booksElms.push(book);
  });


myForm.addEventListener('submit', e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault();
  booksElms.forEach( book =>
    {
    if ( book.textContent == '' )  // set value if empty
      book.textContent = myForm.booktitle.value; 
    });

    var title = document.getElementById("booktitle").value;

newBookAdd = new BookDetails(title);
bookShelf.push(newBookAdd);
var storeBooks = JSON.stringify(bookShelf);
  
localStorage.setItem("storedbookShelf", (storeBooks));
  
  });



  console.log(bookShelf);
```

```css
#shelf {
    height: 150px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(25px,40px));
    align-items: end;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.book {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 100px;
    width:25px;
    display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 5px;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#add-book {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bookshelf">

                    <div id="shelf"></div>
                    
                </div>

<button id="add-book">+</button>

<form id="form" >

                        <label for="booktitle">Book Title</label><br>
                        <input type="text" id="booktitle" name="booktitle"><br>

                        <input type="submit" id="submitform" value="Submit">
                        

                    </form>
```

Comment: You don't seem to have any code that runs when the page is loaded and displays everything in `bookshelf`. You fetch it from localStorage but don't do anything with it.

Comment: I've tried console.logging it and making an alert but I just get null.
Sorry I should have added that.

Comment: Getting `null` on the console before adding books means there is nothing in local storage. Try cleaning up the code a little - it seems you can add a book without a title, and if you add several books without a title, "submitting" a title adds it to all the empty books on the shelf. Double check that you need a `form` element and a submit button - there's nothing in the post to indicate either are necessary. Basically I couldn't reproduce the error as described - it worked for me in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to save and print your bookcase.

Live example here (wihout limit on local storage usage): https://jsfiddle.net/wpexpert/wftjvc3p/

```js
const
    localStorageKey = 'storedbookShelf',
  shelf = document.getElementById('shelf'),
  addBookBtn = document.getElementById('add-book'),
  clearBooksBtn = document.getElementById('clear-books'),
  myForm = document.getElementById('form'),
  formDiv = document.getElementById('formcontainer'),
  submitFormBtn = document.getElementById('submitform'),
  booksElms = [];

const retrieveBookShelf = localStorage.getItem(localStorageKey);
let bookShelf = retrieveBookShelf ? JSON.parse(retrieveBookShelf) : [];

class BookDetails {
  constructor(title) {
    this.title = title
  }
}

function addBookFnc(title) {
  let book = document.createElement('div');
  book.classList.add('book');
  if (title) {
    book.textContent = title;
  }
  shelf.appendChild(book);
  booksElms.push(book);
}

addBookBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  addBookFnc();
});

if (bookShelf) {
  bookShelf.forEach(book => {
    addBookFnc(book?.title);
  });
}

clearBooksBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    localStorage.removeItem(localStorageKey);
});

myForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  let hasEmptyBook = false;

  booksElms.forEach(book => {
   // set value if empty
    if (book.textContent == ''){
      book.textContent = myForm.booktitle.value;
        hasEmptyBook = true;
    }
  });

  if (hasEmptyBook === false) return '';

  let title = document.getElementById("booktitle").value;

  newBookAdd = new BookDetails(title);
  bookShelf.push(newBookAdd);
  const storeBooks = JSON.stringify(bookShelf);

  localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, (storeBooks));

});

console.log(bookShelf);
```

```css
#shelf {
  height: 150px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(25px, 40px));
  align-items: end;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.book {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100px;
  width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 5px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#add-book {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bookshelf">
  <div id="shelf"></div>
</div>
<button id="add-book">+</button>
<form id="form">
  <label for="booktitle">Book Title</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="booktitle" name="booktitle"><br>
  <input type="submit" id="submitform" value="Submit">
</form>

<button id="clear-books">Clear-books</button>
```